# how to unify an object from objects

Tags: javascript

good night, I'm having trouble merging an object inside another

my object currently.

```
{
   "id":7,
   "name":"Pedroo",
   "email":"pedro@hotmail.com",
   "cognitoSub":"9162b350-d19db1b3f",
   "phoneNumber":"+5521997221764",
   "photo":null,
   "createdAt":"2022-10-21T14:48:36.000Z",
   "updatedAt":"2022-10-21T14:48:36.000Z",
   "Account":{
      "userId":7
   }
}
```

and I would like to leave it in a single object

example:

```
{
   "id":7,
   "name":"Pedroo",
   "email":"pedro@hotmail.com",
   "cognitoSub":"9162b350-d19db1b3f",
   "phoneNumber":"+5521997221764",
   "photo":null,
   "createdAt":"2022-10-21T14:48:36.000Z",
   "updatedAt":"2022-10-21T14:48:36.000Z",
   "userId":7
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this method

```
const flattenObj = (ob) => {

// The object which contains the
// final result
let result = {};

// loop through the object "ob"
for (const i in ob) {

    // We check the type of the i using
    // typeof() function and recursively
    // call the function again
    if ((typeof ob[i]) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(ob[i])) {
        const temp = flattenObj(ob[i]);
        for (const j in temp) {

            // Store temp in result
            result[j] = temp[j];
        }
    }

    // Else store ob[i] in result directly
    else {
        result[i] = ob[i];
    }
}
return result;
};
```